# Linker warnings with GLFW

Tags: linker, glfw

I am trying to use GLFW for a school project, and have followed these steps:
1) Download the win32 zip from glfw.org
2) Add /include to my solution's includes
3) Add /lib-msvc100/debug to my solution's libraries
4) Link against glfw.lib and opengl32.lib
5) #include GL/glfw.h

While the project compiles and runs just fine, I can't get around a slew of the following errors:

> Warning LNK4099: PDB 'vc100.pdb' was not found with
>   'glfw.lib(enable.obj)' or at '-projectdir-\Debug\vc100.pdb'; linking object as if no
>   debug info

One other post here ([LNK4099 in GLFW console project with debug configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274551/lnk4099-in-glfw-console-project-with-debug-configuration)) talks about accidently linking both static and dll, but I have not done so. I cannot submit a project with compilation errors :-/

Any idea what's going on here, and how to fix it? Much obliged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the debug version of the GLFW binary, but the vc100.pdb debug information database wasn't included in the zip file. It's a relatively harmless warning and simply means you won't be able to debug normally inside GLFW functions. However, you wouldn't be able to anyway, as the zip file doesn't have the GLFW sources either.

Comment: I had figured as much, but couldn't figure out how to suppress the warning. After talking with my professor, she allowed the warning and graded by hand, instead of using the grading script.

Comment: The only way I know of to avoid the warning would be to compile GLFW yourself, either in debug mode so you get the database file, or in release mode so you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem for me:

Open the GLFW project in the solution and go to C++ general options.  For all platforms, change the debug build's "debug information format" to "Program Database".  Recompile.